# Get next month in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

In OSX on the terminal, how can `cal` be used to obtain the calendar of the next month?

i.e. the following

```
command: "cal -m && date +%m +1"
```

should equate to

```
command: "cal -m 7"
```

and produce:

```
     July 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
m=$(date +'%m'); ((m++)) ; cal -m $m
```

or this:

```
cal $(date -v+1m +'%m %y')
```

Comment: +1 for the 2nd snippet (kudos for showing _next_ year's January in December). The 1st one _potentially_ has the same problem as the accepted answer (doesn't handle _December_ properly), but will actually start to fail in _August_, because `((...))` treats `0`-prefixed numbers as _octals_, and `08` is an invalid octal.